# fstrim always trims a certain amount when run after boot

Tags: linux, ssd, nvme, trim

For some reason, if I run `fstrim -v /` immediately after booting up, it will always trim at least a certain amount regardless of what was done on the disk prior (even if I never really did anything but reboot). For example, the following sequence of events is possible.

1. Boot up.
2. `fstrim -v /` reports at least 42.8 GiB trimmed.
3. `fstrim -v /` a second time reports 0 bytes trimmed, as expected.
4. Immediately reboot.
5. `fstrim -v /` for some reason reports 42.8 GiB trimmed.
6. `fstrim -v /` again report 0 bytes trimmed, as expected.

This interestingly also occurs for any mounted disks, like my storage partition, which happens to be on the same SSD, and is infrequently accessed. Is this possibly some kind of benign SSD quirk? I don't necessarily TRIM at every boot, or even every day, but when I tried to see how many bytes tend to get trimmed over some period of time as an experiment (namely during my day-to-day usage), I noticed this strange quirk. For this partition, it's always 42.8 GiB (I think), and 82.6 GiB for the storage partition that is not frequently accessed. Why might this be? Is this benign?